# Additional sentences for language deconstruction (CEFR levels A1-A2)?

Tags: learning-methods, language-comparison

Tim Ferris' blogpost [How to Learn (But Not Master) Any Language in 1 Hour (Plus: A Favor)](http://fourhourworkweek.com/2007/11/07/how-to-learn-but-not-master-any-language-in-1-hour-plus-a-favor/) describes a "**language deconstruction technique**" to help people find out what a foreign is like before deciding whether they want to learn it. The technique relies on a small set of simple sentences that **expose specific language features in the target language**, for example:

- does the language have a case system,
- does it have verb conjugations,
- how does it express certain basic things such as past, present and future,
- how does it use pronouns,
- what type of syntax does it mainly use (e.g. [SVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb%E2%80%93object) order versus [SOV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93object%E2%80%93verb) order).

Below are the examples from the article:

> 1. The apple is red.
> 2. It is John’s apple.
> 3. I give John the apple.
> 4. We give him the apple.
> 5. He gives it to John.
> 6. She gives it to him.
> 7. Is the apple red?
> 8. The apples are red.
> 9. I must give it to him.
> 10. I want to give it to her.
> 11. I’m going to know tomorrow.
> 12. I can’t eat the apple.
> 13. I have eaten the apple.

The idea is that you find a native speaker of the target language and discuss how these sentences would be translated into the target language. This should give you some clues about the language features listed above.

Some people have applied this to specific languages, e.g.

- [French Grammar Deconstruction (à la Tim Ferriss)](http://simple-french.com/french-language-deconstruction-tim-ferriss/) (the French sentences are read aloud in a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ld6oStvyGtQ), so you also get some information about pronunciation),
- [Tim Ferris: Thai Sentence Deconstruction](http://womenlearnthai.com/index.php/tim-ferris-thai-sentence-deconstruction/),
- [Deconstruct Korean Grammar with 13 Sentences](http://keytokorean.com/blog/challenge/120-topik-16-deconstruct-korean-grammar-with-13-sentences/).

Ferris' list of example sentences is very short, so there may be important language features that don't get uncovered by means of this list. **What sentences should be added to the list to cover language features that are typically learnt at [CEFR levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages#Common_reference_levels) A1 and A2?**

In other words, any additional sentences should help uncover language features in *foreign languages* that the above sentences do not uncover yet (you should mention which feature and at least one language where it is used) and should be basic enough to be learnt at levels A1 and A2 of the CEFR (to remove the element of subjectivity). Proposals to replace sentences are OK. In total, there should not be more than 30 sentences.

The goal is not to cover *all* language features that are learnt at levels A1 and A2; I mention these levels only to exclude grammatical subtleties that you only need at higher levels. In other words, A2 represents the *upper bound* of what needs to be covered. The goal of language deconstruction is to get a rough idea of what the target language is like before you start investing time and energy into learning it.

Comment: I think the way you formulate it now, your question is a bit too open-ended. Maybe you could restrict it somehow? What is, roughly, the number of sentences that you want to have? A few dozen? A few hundred? A few thousand? Do you want to cover all languages in existence, or maybe only some most popular languages?

Comment: In any case, if you have a good specification what you want, this might be a good candidate for a community wiki.

Comment: @michau I have tweaked the question again, especially to cap the number of sentences. The number of target languages is not a criterion. We're only doing *amateur* [contrastive analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrastive_analysis) here ;-) As I mentioned before, the sentences don't need to uncover *all* language features in all foreign languages, but just enough features to help you decide whether you would like learning a specific foreign language.

Comment: Now it's much clearer. But I'm still not sure what the target language group is. It makes a big difference if you just want to cover, say, 30 most popular foreign languages, or all 6000 or so languages that currently exist. The former is much harder, obviously.

Comment: @michau Can you please explain why it would be necessary to define what target languages I want to cover? It's just a bunch of sentences that should be translatable into any language. I see no reason to limit the number of target languages. Illustrations of target languages (in the responses) can pick any target language.

Comment: Just because more languages means more potential grammatical features to cover. For example, there's a lot of polysythetic languages in the world, but they are very rarely learnt as a foreign language by non-linguists.

Comment: @michau Then there is only a low probability that these languages will show up here. Most people currently on LLSE are clearly not linguists (nor SLA teachers).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a workable approach.

A simple example from Spanish:

```
The apple is red.
La manzana es roja.
```

How about *tomato*?

```
The tomato is red.
El tomate es rojo.
```

*Tomate* happens to be masculine, and therefore requires the article *el* instead of *la*, and the adjective that describes it needs to end with *-o*, not *-a*. At the A1/A2 Spanish level you certainly need to know that.

Another example, from Polish:

```
The apple is red.
Jabłko jest czerwone.
I have eaten the apple.
Zjadłem jabłko.
```

Let's try with *tomato* again:

```
The tomato is red.
Pomidor jest czerwony.
I have eaten the tomato.
Zjadłem pomidora.
```

*Jabłko* is neuter and *pomidor* is masculine. If you just try sentences with the former, you may think that the accusative case is equal to the nominative case in Polish. Only if you choose something that happens to be masculine or feminine in Polish, you will see that it's not the case ("tomato" in nominative is *pomidor*, while in accusative it's *pomidora*).

Finally, consider simple Mandarin phrases, that even beginners need to know:

```
one day
一天 "one day"
one week
一個星期 "one 個 week"
one book
一本書 "one 本 book"
```

When you construct the phrase for "one day" you simply juxtapose the characters for "one" and for "day" (which happens to be a measure word, but let's leave that aside). When you combine 一 "one" with 星期 "week", you need to use the measure word 個, which cannot be translated into English in any way. Finally, when you combine 一 "one" with 書 "book", you need to use another untranslatable measure word, 本.

How to construct appropriate sentences in English? **You can't**. Of course, you can have English sentences with nouns of all possible genders in Spanish. And Polish. And Lithuanian. And with nouns that have all basic measure words of Mandarin. And Japanese. And Burmese. But you can never be sure if you cover all important distinctions in a new language you're trying to learn about, unless you cover whole vocabulary for the A1/A2 level, which probably means that you need more than 1000 sentences. And even then, I don't think it's possible to construct basic vocabulary in English that can simply be translated to other languages. In different languages, different things and actions are culturally important, and therefore the basic vocabulary should differ too.

I see the point of having some phrases translated to have a taste of the language, but I think that trying to cover the grammar of all languages at CEFR A1 and A2 is simply setting the bar too high.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it's not English that needs to have all the grammatical features. That is obviously impossible The goal is to make the translations highlight certain grammatical features of the target language. For example, translating "I give John the apple." into German will show that German has a case system, while English doesn't.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe You're right, I edited it out, but that doesn't really change my main point: a small set of sentences will have arbitrary chosen vocabulary and you will never know if you cover all genders, noun classes and important measure words (among other things) in the target language.

Comment: That's fine. You don't need to capture *all* grammar that needs to be covered in levels A1 and A2, but just get an idea of what a language is like without getting into subtleties that you learn only at a higher level.

Comment: "Of course, you can have English sentences with nouns of all possible genders in Spanish." That is not necessary. The goal of the sentence is to uncover whether the target language uses grammatical gender. If it does, further discussion with the native speaker can reveal how many genders the language has.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so here's my another take at it. Instead of providing specific sentences, I'd suggest a way of discovering what the most common grammatical distinctions there are.

Since you seem to be equally interested in all languages, I would look at the [language feature list](http://wals.info/feature) on [WALS](http://wals.info), sort them by number of languages, and make sure that the sentences cover the features from the top of the list. Let's take a look at it:

1. Order of Object and Verb
2. Order of Subject and Verb
3. Order of Subject, Object and Verb
4. Order of Adjective and Noun
5. Postverbal Negative Morphemes
6. Preverbal Negative Morphemes
7. Order of Negative Morpheme and Verb
8. Minor morphological means of signaling negation
9. Relationship between the Order of Object and Verb and the Order of Adjective and Noun
10. Order of Genitive and Noun
11. Order of Demonstrative and Noun
12. ...

1-3 is already covered by your sentences with the indirect and direct object. For 4. we need a phrase such as "the red apple". For 5-8 we need negation, so we can say e.g. "I don't have the red apple", which also covers 9.

Now for 10 we need a genitive and noun, e.g. "John's apple". For 11: a demonstrative and a noun, e.g. "this apple". And so on...

As I look through this list, it seems to me that all the most common features are within A1/A2 level that you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not the intent of my question. What you are suggesting would be more appropriate for Linguistics Stack Exchange.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe What's wrong with this approach?

Comment: I'm only asking for example sentences (plus why they should be added), not for a list of language features. Finding common language features is one of the approaches that can be used to find suitable sentences, but that list should only be a means to an end, not the end itself.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe I did provide a sentence: "I don't have the red apple". Is it a problem that I also provided reasoning behind it and a way to build more such sentences? I don't get it.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I had apparently overlooked the example.

Comment: I don't see why you posted another answer when I personally liked your first one more and it seemed to have more relevance to the question.

Comment: @fi12 My previous answer was under the assumption that the goal is to cover *all* A1/A2 grammar. I explained why it's impossible. But then the OP explained that he didn't need all A1/A2 grammatical points to be covered, and A2 is just an upper bound. So I posted this answer, which explains a pretty general way to construct these sentences. Is it the explanation in this answer unclear or do you think that the generated sentences aren't going to be relevant?

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one adverbs. Adverbs are basically adjectives for verbs or other adjectives. An example sentence could be:

> The apple is very shiny. 
>   The man walks very fast.

"very" is used to help the reader know how shiny or in the second case, how fast. Yes, "very" is subject to opinion but there should be some similarity in the mental image provided by the sentence.

Past, Present, Future. All speakers should know these three tenses regardless of skill:

> Past: I finished the dish. 
>   Present: I am finishing the dish. 
>   Future: I will finish the dish.

The usage of suffixes or extra verbs are also present (-ing for an action that is continuing i.e. progressive, -ed for past, etc.)

And clearly, all of the above are used in English.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In your first example, only "very" is an adverb; it modifies "shiny", not the verb. "Shiny" (here) is an [predicative adjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_expression#Predicative_vs._attributive_adjectives). In "He walks very fast", "fast" would be an adverb.